# as removing a line commented python file?

Tags: python, file

Could someone tell me how to delete a line commented a python file such comments need to delete hundreds of files Python like this:

```
{
    'active': False, 
    'installable': True, 
    'test': [
        # 'Test / purchase_order.yml' 
        # 'Test / purchase_picking.yml' 
        # 'Test / purchase_validation.yml' 
        # 'Test / sale_order.yml' 
        # 'Test / sale_validation.yml' 
    ]
}
```

I searched for these types of topics in this forum but can not find anything specific as I need, thank you for your attention

Comment: Put a little effort in your question. Some formatting and punctuation would be nice. As is, it's unreadable.

Comment: Do all of the lines to remove have the `# 'Test` pattern in them?

Comment: Do you want to delete the whole line that starts with `#` OR do you **just** want to delete the `#` and leave the rest of the line intact?

Comment: I want Trashing the lines of code that have been comets (# 'test / sale_validation.yml') 

and leave lines if comments are (#this is a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an improved version of Kasra's code:

```
with open('my_file.py', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()[0] != '#']

with open('my_file.py', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

## Edit

Hopefully, this version complies with J Guzman Guzman's new requirements...

```
with open('my_file.py', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line for line in f if not line.replace(' ','').lower().startswith("#'test/")]

with open('my_file.py', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mauro, for the improvement. (I *really* need to get some sleep. :) )

Comment: You can remove the ".readlines()" part, `[line for line in f if ...]` avoids building an extra list with the file contents. A regex like `r"\s*#\s*'Test /"` would work also.

Comment: @tdelaney : Good thinking!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('my_file.py','r') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()

with open('my_file.py','w') as f:
    for line in lines :
        if line.strip().startswith('#'):
            lines.remove(line)
    f.writelines(lines)
```

In this code first we read all lines then for any line we use `strip` (delete spaces) and then if the line have been started with `'#'` we delete it .

Also if you have your comment inside other codes you can use `regex` and with `re.sub` you can do it:

Demo:

my_file.py:

```
################comment###########
{
    'active': False, 
    'installable': True, 
    'test': [
        # 'Test / purchase_order.yml' 
        # 'Test / purchase_picking.yml' 
        # 'Test / purchase_validation.yml' 
        # 'Test / sale_order.yml' 
        # 'Test / sale_validation.yml' 
    ]
}
```

your code :

```
import re

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()

with open('test.txt','w') as f:
 s=re.sub(r'#[\w \S]*','',''.join(lines))
 f.writelines(s)
```

output:

```
{
    'active': False, 
    'installable': True, 
    'test': [





    ]
}
```

Comment: Those lines *don't* `startswith('#')`. Also, your syntax is incorrect (missing colon, incorrect indentation).

Comment: thanks for replying, the problem is that I have if I need comments if implement that code, I will delete comments that if they go in my python file, but such comments; #'Test/sale_validation.yml', which are depreciated need to remove

Comment: Why cast `line.strip(' ')` to `str`? It is already a string. Also, you can just use `line.strip()` to remove *all* whitespace, which won't break if it uses e.g. tabs.

Comment: Also, `remove()` is pretty inefficient if there are a lot of lines to process.

Comment: @JGuzmanGuzman do want to uncommented the comments lines? and remove just `#`

Comment: It looks like the OP wants to strip out the whole line if the 1st non-space char in it is a `#`. But I could be wrong. :)

Comment: #this comment not want to be elimne 
#'test / sale_validation.yml' this if I want to remove                      this is a problem

Comment: @JGuzmanGuzman i suggest edit your answer and add the output you want to question !

Comment: ! # / Usr / bin / python # - * - encoding: utf-8 - * - ############################## ################################### #coments #coments ########### ################################################## ####### {'activo': Falso, 'instalable': Es Cierto, "prueba": [# 'Test / purchase_order.yml' eliminar tales commentss # 'Test / purchase_picking.yml' eliminar tales comentarios # ' Prueba / purchase_validation.yml 'eliminar tales comentarios #' Prueba / sale_order.yml '#' Test / sale_validation.yml ']}

Comment: i add a answer with regex for you i think you want that

Comment: Apart from the inefficiency of using `remove`, which has to scan through the **whole** list until it finds the line, for every line you want to remove, it's dangerous to remove items from a list that you're iterating over, since it disturbs the indices. And in fact your code as it currently stands doesn't remove all the commented lines from the test data. (I just tested it).

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of lines formatted *exactly* like what you have described you can use the SED stream editor on the linux command line:

This command replaces the character sequence of `# '` with just a `'`:

```
sed "s/# '/'/" /path/to/code/file.py
```

When I pass it your example code it yields the following:

```
{
    'active': False, 
    'installable': True, 
    'test': [
        'Test / purchase_order.yml' 
        'Test / purchase_picking.yml' 
        'Test / purchase_validation.yml' 
        'Test / sale_order.yml' 
        'Test / sale_validation.yml' 
    ]
}
```

Comment: And if the OP wants to actually delete those lines: `sed '/^[ ]*#/d'`

Comment: But of course we're _supposed_ to be doing this in Python. :)